# How to check if the column is FK, PK or normal . C# with MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I'm need a way in C#(MySQL) "if it is possible" to check if the column that I'm working with is a Foreign key, Primary key or normal column

Comment: Is this for some kind of tool, or are you going to change some behaviour depending on the type of column?

Comment: I wanna test the column if its is FK so I make function that triggers when it sees a FK and do auto fill for example a comboBox.